# Why can't I connect to Internet from machine root, but can from virtual machine

Tags: 16.04, ssh, kvm-virtualization, qemu, ping

ubuntu 16.04, KVM , QEMU

This was all working fine until a few days ago, but now I find that I cannot ping the internet from the machine's root account, but I can do so from a Windows KVM instance running on that machine. Also, though I can ssh into the machine from my local network, I can no longer ssh into any the the virtual machines from the root of the machine. I have not changed anything for quite a while.

```
bbands@yang:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.14.78) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
```

That seems really strange. The name is being resolved, but contact is not permitted. Any idea as to what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the firewall to the default to allow all outbound traffic solved this problem.

```
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
```

The mystery as to why this was necessary remains.